Absolute path after building app by webpack with webtorrent and electron
I have an app with electron forge, webtorrent and webpack. I created it using 2 commands:
npm init electron-app@latest my-app -- --template=webpack
yarn add webtorrent

Add import to main.js
import WebTorrent from "webtorrent";

And:
yarn package

After this my application only works on my computer because after the build there is an absolute path in the application code:
(0,n.createRequire)("file:///Users/prof1/projects/pw_castle/launcher_test/node_modules/node-datachannel/lib/index.js")("../build/Release/node_datachannel.node")

I don't understand why this is happening. If I remove the webtorrent import from my main.js, the absolute path disappears from the build. I know that webtorrent requires additional configuration for webpack. But it seems this is only required when used in a browser? Problem is only with webtorrent, other libs work perferctly. I tried different versions of webtorrent. It didn't help me.
My webpack.main.config.js (default for electron forge):
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  module: {
    rules: require('./webpack.rules'),
  },
};


webpack.rules.js (default for electron forge)
module.exports = [
  {
    test: /native_modules[/\\].+\.node$/,
    use: 'node-loader',
  },
  {
    test: /[/\\]node_modules[/\\].+\.(m?js|node)$/,
    parser: { amd: false },
    use: {
      loader: '@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader',
      options: {
        outputAssetBase: 'native_modules',
      },
    },
  },
];


And forge.config.js (default for electron forge):
const { FusesPlugin } = require('@electron-forge/plugin-fuses');
const { FuseV1Options, FuseVersion } = require('@electron/fuses');

module.exports = {
  packagerConfig: {
    asar: true,
  },
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-zip',
      platforms: ['darwin'],
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-deb',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-rpm',
      config: {},
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/plugin-webpack',
      config: {
        mainConfig: './webpack.main.config.js',
        renderer: {
          config: './webpack.renderer.config.js',
          entryPoints: [
            {
              html: './src/index.html',
              js: './src/renderer.js',
              name: 'main_window',
              preload: {
                js: './src/preload.js',
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
    new FusesPlugin({
      version: FuseVersion.V1,
      [FuseV1Options.RunAsNode]: false,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableCookieEncryption]: true,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableNodeOptionsEnvironmentVariable]: false,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableNodeCliInspectArguments]: false,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableEmbeddedAsarIntegrityValidation]: true,
      [FuseV1Options.OnlyLoadAppFromAsar]: true,
    }),
  ],
};


Add to webpack.rules.js:
 {
   test: /webtorrent[/\\].+\.node$/,
   use: 'node-loader',
 },

Change webpack.main.config.js to:
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  module: {
    rules: require('./webpack.rules'),
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json'],
    alias: {
      // Add any necessary aliases here
    },
    fallback: {
      fs: false,
    },
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'), 
    filename: 'main.js',
  },
};

Clean before next pack:
yarn clean
yarn package

And unless you have a reason not to:
yarn add node-loader @vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader

It doesn't work: The installed version of @vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader does not appear to be compatible with Forge

And with previous version of @vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader changed nothing

Ok, but except from the installation, also all the other changes change nothing?

Nothing, I still have absolute imports in my build files

Ill reproduce later and ill update, can you share sample of your app

You can reproduce it by npm init electron-app@latest my-app -- --template=webpack and adding import WebTorrent from 'webtorrent' to main.js

I am getting this issue too for some other package. It seems electron forge is using the absolute path rather than the relative path. It's weird but all my packages work except this singular native package (the only native package I have). So I can use it in dev mode but can't ship just like you.

@avifen The new version of @vercel/webpack... does not work with current version of Electron forge according to others on their git so it's an unrelated issue. I am trying to find an answer for this, but it is such a weird thing. The module I have is get-windows which is a native module.
I think somehow whatever is packaging native apps is causing this oddity?
